# How can I use environment variables in Chrome-extension-development?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-developers-console

Can somebody suggest me how can I use environment variables while developing chrome extension so that my API Key is not exposed...

Is there any way so that I can put my API key in manifest.json file and use it?

Comment: The API key is exposed only to the user but environment variables are exposed just the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.